# Load application in console and use its environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I try to write a little ruby script, which shall load a ruby application with the command `load`. That works fine.
But I want to use the loaded environment to run commands, but I don't know how to get it working.
It looks like:

```
load('script/console')
LoadedClass.find(1)
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your script and then use the [rails runner](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-runner) to run it.